# Javascript format different strings into a standard interval format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have strings coming in that might be any of the following list:

```
7

5:45

11:05

23:5

14:3
```

and I want to always end up with like:

```
07:00
05:45
11:05
23:50
14:30
etc
```

How can I write a nice function in Javascript take this in and give me the correct output? Remembering that the single hour values won't have a colon, like 7 at the begining of the list.

I tried using a PadZero function:

```
    Number.prototype.padZero= function(len){
  var s= String(this), c= '0';
  len= len || 2;
  while(s.length < len) s= c + s;
  return s;
}
```

with

```
var formattedY = this.x.padZero().toString().replace('.',':');
```

p.s. my actual values come back as 11.5 or 23.45, but I want 11:50 and 23:45

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? What roadblocks have you hit?

Comment: Would it be an option to solve the issue at it's root, e.g. create proper values in the first place? Seems more reasonable.

Comment: I have tired a few things on my own, I tired momentJS and I tried padding out the strings, but I just couldn't get everything working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work. Stack Overflow is not a code writing forum.

Comment: No in this case it isn't reasonable to solve the issue at the root. I have to solve it here.

Comment: @PaulDuer please include your best attempt in your question.

Comment: 23:5 for 23:50 seems just sooooo wrong.

Comment: Yeah that's why I want rid of it.

Comment: It seems far more sensible that 23:5 is 23:05 since it's more common to omit leading rather than trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should solve your problem.

```js
function format_time(invalid_time_string) {
  var corrected_time = invalid_time_string;
  if (invalid_time_string.length === 1) {
    invalid_time_string = "0" + invalid_time_string + ":00";
    corrected_time = invalid_time_string;
  } else {
    if (invalid_time_string.length < 5) {
      var hours_minutes = invalid_time_string.split(":");
      if (hours_minutes[0].length != 2) {
        var corrected_hours = "0" + hours_minutes[0];
      } else {
        var corrected_hours = hours_minutes[0];
      }
      if (hours_minutes[1].length != 2) {
        var corrected_minutes = hours_minutes[1] + "0";
      } else {
        var corrected_minutes = hours_minutes[1];
      }
      corrected_time = corrected_hours + ":" + corrected_minutes;
    }
  }
  return corrected_time;
}

var correct_time = format_time("5:45");
console.log(correct_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this simple switch will make the trick

```js
function getHour(hour) {
     var newHour;
     switch (hour.length) {
        case 1:
            newHour = '0'+hour+':00';
            break;
        case 2:
            newHour = hour+':00';
            break;
        case 3:
            newHour = '0'+hour+'0';
            break;
        case 4:
            newHour = hour.charAt(2) == ":" ? hour+'0' : '0'+hour;      
            break;
        default:
            newHour = hour;
     }
  
     console.log(newHour);
}

getHour('7');     //07:00
getHour('8:5');   //08:50
getHour('17:35'); //17:35
getHour('02:5');  //02:50
getHour('2:43');  //02:43
```

Comment: `getHour('5:45')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
frm('7:10');
frm('17:01');
frm('1:1');
frm('7');

function frm(val) {
  var parts = val.split(':');
  
  if(parts.length === 1) {
    parts.push('00');
  }
  
  var res = parts.map(function(i) {
    return ('0' + i).slice(-2);
  }).join(':');
  
  console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getCleanTimeString(timeString)
{
    if(m=timeString.match(/(\d+)(?:[:](\d+))?/))
    {
        var h = parseInt(m[1],10);
        var m = parseInt((m[2]+'0').substr(0,2),10)||0;
        return ('0' + h).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + m).slice(-2);
    }
    return timeString;//failure
}
alert(getCleanTimeString('7'));
alert(getCleanTimeString('5:45'));
alert(getCleanTimeString('11:05'));
alert(getCleanTimeString('23:5'));
alert(getCleanTimeString('14:3'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5p9bqjwy/1/

Comment: it's wrong -- `getCleanTimeString('23:5')` should return `23:50` not `23:05`

Answer (score 0):

I took the code from the first answer to come in and came up with this:

```
  String.prototype.frm= function() {
  var val = this;
  var parts = val.split(':');

  if(parts.length === 1) {
    parts.push('00');
  }
  var res = parts.map(function(i) {
    return ('0' + i).slice(-2);
  }).join(':');
  return(res);
};
```

which I can call with this:

```
var formattedY = this.x.toString().replace('.',':').frm();
```

and that gets the PERFECT result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun one:

```js
function pad(str) {
  switch (str.indexOf(':')) {
    case -1: str = (str.length - 1 ? '' : 0) + str + ':00'; break;
    case 1: str = 0 + str + (str.length < 4 ? 0 : ''); break;
    case 2: str = str + (str.length < 5 ? 0 : ''); break;
  }
  
  return str;
}

console.log(pad('7'));
console.log(pad('12'));
console.log(pad('7:5'));
console.log(pad('7:55'));
console.log(pad('55:7'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to not want to write you're own code, consider:

```js
function weirdPadding(s) {
  var b = s.split(':');
  return ('0' + b[0]).slice(-2) + ':' + ((b[1] || '0') + '0').slice(0, 2); 
}

['7','2:3','23:2','12:45'].forEach(function(t){
  console.log(t + ' => ' + weirdPadding(t))
});
```

However, I would expect 2:3 should be 2:03 since it's more common to omit leading zeros rather than trailing zeros.

In the latest browsers you can do:

```js
function weirdPadding(s) {
  return (/:/.test(s)? s : s + ':').split(':').reduce((h, m) => ('0' + h).slice(-2) + ':' + ((m || '0') + '0').slice(0, 2));
}

['7','2:3','23:2','12:45'].forEach(t => console.log(t + ' => ' + weirdPadding(t)));
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why people have to be snarky. No, in this case I didn't want to write my own code. I wanted people who are well trained in the subject to answer the question so that not only would I have a bulletproof solution, but I could learn from those who know more than me. So while I thank you for your input, next time leave the snark at home!